GeoMesa/Accumulo Attribute level visibility
I want to enable attribute level visibilities where each attribute has a list of visiblities
such as admin,user,poweruser. When a user queries my endpoint, I want to pass its role such as
admin and want to return ALL attributes as admin is the highest visibility. When I query GeoMesa,
the system will query as a root user but will pass the admin role to retrieve appropriate attributes.
Is GeoMesa 4.0.1/Accumulo 2.1.0 able to handle this scenario? Can you provide examples of such scenarios?

Yes, GeoMesa supports this scenario. The documentation has a tutorial on feature-level authorizations. Attribute-level authorizations would be similar, but require setting labels differently, as described in the documentation here.
Visibilities do not work quite the way you describe them, though. A visibility label is a Boolean expression, so in your example it would be admin|user|poweruser. There is also no concept of hierarchy - e.g. in your example, your application would have to provide the logic for admins to also get the user authorization. See the Accumulo documentation for a complete description.

I am trying to implement this solution, however I am having trouble reading the data based on the root auths. I followed the Attribute-level visibilities when storing to the db. Can you link some documentation that can help with verifying that data is stored correctly and reading of the data?
